# How to keep netcat open using it as a TCP tunnel?

Tags: tcp, netcat

Say I am doing something like this:
(bsd variant of nc)

```
nc -k -l 8080 <fifo | nc 10.90.34.18 80 >fifo
```

This works great, I can use the server this is run on as a proxy to reach 10.90.34.18.

However, after performing a curl, it looks like the second nc command exits.

How can I prevent this?

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: "This works great" Does it? How? What happens when the server on 10.90.34.18:80 closes the connection?

Comment: Shell is bash. When the server closes the connection I believe this is what causes the second netcat process to exit. I suppose it would be more correct to say "This works great for a single connection".

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to use a while loop like so:

```
while true
do
  nc 10.90.34.18 80 >fifo
done < <(nc -k -l 8080 <fifo)
```